# Solucionar: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, html, laravel, laragon

Me sale este error al querer correr mi programa, se supone que mi tabla solicitud tiene una llave foranea a users, y tengo otra tabla llamada evento_divulgacion la cual también tiene una llave foránea a solicitud (evento_divulgación apunta a solicitud y solicitud apunta a users). No se si las relaciones que hice están mal, he buscado soluciones en otros lados pero no me ayudan, talvez se me pasó un user_id, hay una forma de que eseo este definido por default?. He estado checando mucho mis controladores y modelos y no enceuntro donde está el user_id que me está dando problema, aquí está mi código:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('appellido_paterno')->nullable();
            $table->string('appellido_materno')->nullable();
            $table->string('telefono_solicitante')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            // $table->foreignId('rol_usuario')->constrained('rol');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });


        Schema::create('solicitud', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('solicitante')->constrained('users');
            $table->string('identificador');
        });

Schema::create('evento_divulgacion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('solicitud_evento')->constrained('solicitud');
            $table->string('nombre_evento');
            $table->string('anfitrion');
            $table->string('grupos');//checkbox
            $table->string('lugar_evento');
            $table->string('fecha_evento');
            $table->string('HoraInicio_evento');
            $table->string('HoraFin_evento');
            $table->string('Descripcion');
            $table->string('Actividades');//checkbox
            $table->string('oficio_evento')->nullable();
            $table->string('Transporte')->nullable();
            $table->string('Firma')->nullable();
            
        });
```

Mis modelos:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */

     public function solicitudes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SolicitudesModel::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'rol_usuario',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}

class SolicitudesModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table="solicitud";
    protected $fillable = [
        'solicitante',
        'identificador',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function solicitudDivulgacion()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(FormulariosModel::class);
    }
}


class FormulariosModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table="evento_divulgacion";
    protected $fillable=[
        'solicitud_evento',
        'nombre_evento',
        'anfitrion',
        'lugar_evento',
        'fecha_evento',
        'HoraInicio_evento',
        'HoraFin_evento',
        'Descripcion',
        'Actividades',
        'oficio_evento',
        'Firma',
    ];

    public function solicitud()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SolicitudesModel::class);
    }
    
}
```

Mis controladores:

```
class SolicitudesController extends Controller
{

   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Crear una nueva solicitud
    $solicitud = new SolicitudesModel;
    $solicitud->solicitante = $user->id;
    $solicitud->identificador = SolicitudesModel::max('identificador') + 1;
    $solicitud->save();

    // Crear una nueva solicitud de promoción asociada a la solicitud creada anteriormente
    $solicitudPD = new FormulariosModel;
    $solicitudD->solicitud_evento = $solicitud->solicitante;
    $solicitudD->save();

    return redirect()->route('divulgacionForm');
}

}

class FormulariosController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function divulgacionForm(Request $req)
    {
        $fDivulgacion= new FormulariosModel();
/////
        // obtener el usuario autenticado
        $user = $req->user();
        
       // crear una nueva solicitud
        $solicitud = $user->solicitudes()->create([]);

      // crear una nueva solicitud de promoción y relacionarla con la solicitud creada
        $fDivulgacion->solicitud_evento = $solicitud->id;
////7
        $fDivulgacion->nombre_evento=$req->nombre_evento;

         $grupos = implode(',', $req->only('checkbox1', 'checkbox2', 'checkbox3', 'checkbox4', 'checkbox5', 'checkbox6','checkbox7', 'checkbox8', 'checkbox9', 'checkbox10'));
         $fDivulgacion->grupos = $grupos;

         $fDivulgacion->lugar_evento=$req->lugar_evento;
         $fDivulgacion->fecha_evento=$req->fecha_evento;
         $fDivulgacion->HoraInicio_evento=$req->HoraInicio_evento;
         $fDivulgacion->HoraFin_evento=$req->HoraFin_evento;
         $fDivulgacion->Descripcion=$req->Descripcion;
         $Actividades= implode(',', $req->only('checkbox1A', 'checkbox2A', 'checkbox3A', 'checkbox4A', 'checkbox5A', 'checkbox6A'));
         $fDivulgacion->Actividades = $Actividades;

        // $file=$req->file('oficio_evento');
        // $req->file('oficio_evento')->storeAs('public',$file->getClientOriginalName());   
        // $fDivulgacion->oficio_evento=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            
        //  $fDivulgacion->Transporte=$req->Transporte;
        //  $fDivulgacion->Firma=$req->Firma;
         $fDivulgacion->save();
         return redirect('/Divulgacion');
         
    }
    
}
```

Ojalá me puedan ayudar :(

También me sale esto en la pagina:
INSERT INTO
`solicitud` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
VALUES
(2, 2023 -04 -25 23: 02: 11, 2023 -04 -25 23: 02: 11)

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Como no estas usando nombres que por convencion espera laravel, tendrias que [pasar el nombre de la clave foranea como segundo argumento al método belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Por otra lado si lees el trazo del error completo en `/tu-proyecto/storage/logs/laravel.log`, probablemente te diga en que archivo y linea se lanzo la excepcion

Comment: Muchas gracias <3

Comment: Si con eso ya lo solucionaste, por favor [escribe una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answerhttps://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) explicando como lo hiciste. Si tienes alguna duda/problema puntual, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/591719/edit) tu pregunta en base a lo que hayas leido en los enlaces del comentario anterior